# npm version mismatchs command line vs control panel

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

Issue : npm version mismatches command line vs control panel

When i tried to upgrade the npm using the command `npm-windows-upgrade@10.15.1`,  thrown the error as npm throws 'npm-windows-upgrade' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
But surprisingly when i go and check in the control panel under the features and programs i see the version as 10.15.1,but when i checked via command line the version shows as 6.4.1.

Note : I have set system variable path as

See the below screenshots as well as log file C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Node.js is 10.15.1, npm is 6.4.1. npm 10 doesn’t exist (6.7.0 is the latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused between Nodejs version and npm version. Nodejs is v 10.15.1 and npm is v 6.4.1. Both are not same and their versions are different.

Comment: Thank you both of you for the quick response .Yes you are right i was confused!